# How relation country group field to invoice custom field in Odoo or OpenERP?

Tags: python, odoo

this is my first question here!
I want to know how to relation `export_message` text field and `dual_box` boolean field in Country Group form to `x_message` text field and `x_dual` boolean field in the invoice form.

And I want to know how can i get the country group of a country.
Let me explain that...

**For example:**

I have 3 country groups (A, B and C) and I have 5 countries (1,2,3,4,5).

Then, Country Group **A** has country *(1 and 5)*, Country Group **B** has *(2 and 3)* and Country Group **C** has *(1 and 4)*.
In the invoice form I have a customer with an address and a Country.

How can I get the country group in the invoice if the customer's country is 1 and save it in a custom field for example?

*I'm working with Odoo 12*

**My CountryGroup Class**

```py
class CountryGroup(models.Model):
   _name = 'country.group'

   name = fields.Char()
   country_ids = fields.Many2many("res.country")
   export_message = fields.Text(string="Export Message")
   dual_box = fields.Boolean(string="Dual Box")
```

**My Invoice Class**

```py
class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

    x_confirm_message = fields.Boolean(string='Confirm Print Message')
    x_message = fields.Text(string='Message', related='')
    x_dual = fields.Boolean(string="Dual Box", related='')
```

Thank you

Comment: You need to add a [computed field](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/fr/developer/reference/orm.html#computed-fields) that depends on the customer's country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a computed field on country_group of account_invoice model:

```
class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

   country_group = fields.Many2one('country.group', 'Country Group', 
   compute="_find_country_group")
    x_confirm_message = fields.Boolean(string='Confirm Print Message')
    x_message = fields.Text(string='Message', related='country_group.export_message')
    x_dual = fields.Boolean(string="Dual Box", related='country_group.dual_box')

   @api.depends('customer_id')
   def _find_country_group(self):
        # Get country of the customer
        country_id = self.env['res.partner'].search([('id', '=', 
        self.customer_id.id)]).country_id
        # Get country_group based on customer's country
        country_gp_id = self.env['rel.country.group'].search([('country_id', '=', country_id.id)], limit=1)
        self.country_group = country_gp_id

class ResCountry(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.country'
    
    country_gp_ids = fields.Many2many("country.group", 'rel_country_group', 'country_id', 'country_group_id')


class CountryGroup(models.Model):
   _name = 'country.group'

   name = fields.Char()
   country_ids = fields.Many2many("res.country", 'rel_country_group', 'country_group_id', 'country_id')
   export_message = fields.Text(string="Export Message")
   dual_box = fields.Boolean(string="Dual Box")

   @api.model
   def create(self, vals):
       gpA = [1, 5]
       gpB = [2, 3]
       if vals['country_ids'].ids in gpA:
           vals['name'] = 'Group A'
       elif vals['country_ids'].ids in gpB:
           vals['name'] = 'Group B'
       ...
       return super(CountryGroup, self).create(vals)
```

In odoo v14, you can just check *many2many in many2many* i.e *list in list*
In odoo v12, You have to loop through each many2many to check.

```
       if [x for x in vals['country_ids'].ids if x in gpA]:
           vals['name'] = 'Group A'
       elif [x for x in vals['country_ids'].ids if x in gpB]:
           vals['name'] = 'Group B'
```